# VBA Loop in Excel wont recognize time

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a spreadsheet that will allow users to copy events during a specific 15 minute interval to specific sheet in the workbook. The time intervals run from midnight to 23:45. The code works fine for copying anything that happened at or before 6:45 but anything after that just comes up blank. I have manually checked the data and there are definitely events on the primary sheet that happen after 6:45 and should be copied over. The data is all being pulled from the same Oracle table so the time formats should be the same.

Here is a piece of code that actually works:

```
'Core - Orange 06:45        
        If ActiveCell.Address = "$AC$6" Then                
        If Range("AC6").Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Exceptions Reported"        
        Else:        
        Sheets("Exceptions").Range("A4", "H50").Clear
        Sheets("Core").Select        
        I = 2
        X = 4        
        Do While Sheets("Core").Range("A" & I).Value <> ""        
        If Range("J" & I).Value <= TimeSerial(6, 45, 0) And Range("K" & I).Value > TimeSerial(6, 45, 0) Then        
        Range("A" & I, "H" & I).Select
        Selection.Copy        
        Sheets("Exceptions").Select        
        Range("A" & X).Select        
        ActiveSheet.Paste        
        I = I + 1
        X = X + 1        
        Sheets("Core").Select        
        Else:        
        Sheets("Exceptions").Select
        Range("A1").Select                
        I = I + 1                        
        End If        
        Loop    
    End If    
    End If
```

Here is the code that is not working:

```
'Core - Orange 07:00        
        If ActiveCell.Address = "$AD$6" Then        
        If Range("AD6").Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Exceptions Reported"        
        Else:        
        Sheets("Exceptions").Range("A4", "H50").Clear
        Sheets("Core").Select        
        I = 2
        X = 4        
        Do While Sheets("Core").Range("A" & I).Value <> ""        
        If Range("J" & I).Value <= TimeSerial(7, 0, 0) And Range("K" & I).Value > TimeSerial(7, 0, 0) Then                        
        Range("A" & I, "H" & I).Select
        Selection.Copy        
        Sheets("Exceptions").Select        
        Range("A" & X).Select        
        ActiveSheet.Paste        
        I = I + 1
        X = X + 1        
        Sheets("Core").Select        
        Else:        
        Sheets("Exceptions").Select
        Range("A1").Select                
        I = I + 1                        
        End If        
        Loop    
    End If    
    End If
```

The two codes should be identical except for the initial cells which I updated. I have tried using different time formats but nothing seemed to work. Any help or suggestions on how to get past this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you have a value, can you paste to be sure, it looks fine for 7am  (also you can skip using .Select so much)   set sheet as var and use shCore.Range() etc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about using var, I'm still new to this so I'm sure my code is on the sloppy side. I pasted the raw data out and it looks just fine. It comes up as the same formats as anything before 7:00, so I'm still stumped. :(

Comment: Expressions like `If Range("J" & I).Value` are the same as `If ActiveSheet.Range("J" & I).Value` By the end of the Do loop you might have either "Core" or "Exceptions" as the active sheet which could change the behaviour of the next loop iteration. Try using `With ... End With` or fully qualifying your references

Comment: Are you in the Pacific timezone, by any chance?  I ask because 7 hours (the point when things fail) would be your offset from GMT now, and it might be worth checking if one clock is doing things in GMT and the other in local time.  Just a hunch.

Comment: Hi, Ralph. I am on Pacific Time myself but the data is all formatted for Eastern Time.  I added a countifs query to the sheet looking for the same criteria and it was able to recognize the appropriate entries and count them correctly. I have even gone so far as to manually overwrite the times and enter them manually to see if it was a formatting issue, but no luck.

Comment: Looks like the problem wasn't the time format, the issue was occurring when vba was trying to copy and paste the data to the other sheet. Not sure what the issue was or why it didn't impact anything before 7 but I changed the code Exce.Range("A" & X, "H" & X).Value = Core.Range("A" & I, "H" & I).Value and it worked fine. Thank you everyone for the assistance, and Steven, thanks for the advise about not using select as much. It really cleaned up my code. Thanks!